# HTML swap-image to fit box

Tags: html, css, image, dreamweaver, swap

I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 and I added a swap behavior to an image in an html document. Basically, the swap property is supposed to pop up at its original size and restore on mouse out. The problem I'm facing is that the image swapped fills the screen. I've tried adding width: px and height: px properties to the img src string but that didn't work either. Here's the snippet:

```
<div class="caption lft glow2" data-x="600" data-y="615" data-speed="600" data-start="200" data-easing="easeOutExpo"><img src="img/glow.png" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','img/intro-1.jpg',1)"  width="131" height="124" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"></div>
```

and here's the css:

```
.caption.glow2 {
position: absolute;
padding: 6px 10px;
margin: 0px;
border-width: 0px;
border-style: none;
background: transparent;
opacity: 5;
```

Please help

Comment: Please post all relevant code (html/css/javascript). Also try recreating this problem on jsfiddle.net if possible so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I made a rollover instead. Thank you!